# How to refresh particular div in the html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am getting a problem to reflect the value in the view, I don't want to load the complete page because its very costly to load the page,

I have two controllers(controller1 and controller2), one service(service1) and two views(modalwindow.html and product.html).

The scenario is:
1.User is on product.html(contains multiple accordions) and user explicitly close all the accordions.

2.User clicked on icon which opened modal window, since it's opened the modal window it's not going to change  the URL on the address bar.

3.Modal window(Modalwindow.html ) has the link of **show product**, since the product page is the active page(show product is the accordion which closed by user explicitly) on the browser.

4. on the click of link, appropriate accordion should be open on the product.html

I am communicating between modal window controller (controller2.js) and product page(controller1.js) through service (service.js), I am calling controller2

how to fix this issue without loading a complete page

Comment: Can you create a fiddle recreating your problem? It might help to understand and solve your question.

Comment: hi Sniels , tried to create the similar kind of program with accordions http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/1461/

Comment: The modal doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Sniels, I have update the code and explained the scenario in the code form. http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/1486

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the modal closes when a product is selected, it can [return the value to the calling controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259351/584846).  Then it opens the specified accordion.

Comment: Brent, actually I am using event handler for calling the productcontroller from modalController, so it's updating the value perfectly in the controller but that value is not reflecting on the view(product.html)

Comment: The modal creates a new `$scope`.  You may need to pass the value from the modal to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around in your fiddle. You are mixing two ways of showing your categories in the fiddle: an accordion value, and two boolean values (categoryAccordion, productAccordion). I moved to using one way and it seems to work with the eventCallback. Also, you checked wrongly for your 'args' in the eventCallback. You're passing it back as an array, so get the value out of the array first.
Also, you checked wrongly for your 'args' in the eventCallback.`

```
if (args[0] == 'Product') {
  $scope.productAccordion = true;
  $scope.categoryAccordion = false;
} else {
  $scope.productAccordion = false;
  $scope.categoryAccordion = true;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/1487/).

---

Should it not be working in your real code, it might have something to do with the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928840/angularjs-service-broadcast-and-watch-not-triggering-on-receiving-controller).